How to increment string in variable using loop in SAS
I am a beginner user in SAS. I have a table Dose_turn with columns Month for month and Doses for dose of different products. I want to set value of doses of specific months to 0 using a loop wherever its the specific product P13.
If I want to change the value of dose of just one month, the code is simple and is as follows:
Data Dose_Trn_2;
Set Dose_Trn;
if Prd_Name = 'P13' and Month= 'Mnth_1' then Doses=0;
run;

Now if i want to change for example for 4 months, can I achieve the same using a loop where month automatically takes in the values 'Mnth_1', 'Mnth_2', 'Mnth_3', 'Mnth_4' based on some condition/increment in the loops like do while or do until loops. I tried using %let and & inside a do loop as shown below:
Data Dose_Trn_m12;
Set Dose_Trn;
do i=1 to 4 by 1;
   %let initial = i;
   if Prd_Name = 'PCV13' and Month= "Mnth_&initial" then Doses=0;
end;
run;

However the above code did not change the value of doses to 0 for Mnth_1, Mnth_3, Mnth_3 and Mnth_4 as I expected. %let and & worked when not used inside a do loop but with the do loop its not working as the doses value didnt change. The reason why I want to implement loop is the months for which doses need to be changed can vary each time based on some prior conditions of data of that month. Can someone suggest a workaround for this problem?

Neither of these change Month.

Based on value of month, I want to change doses. But my month variable string needs to be incremented each time like from Mnth_1 to Mnth_2 to Mnth_3 and so on which i dont want to do manually but maybe achieve through loops if possible.

The reason being I may have to change the value of doses not for 4 but 20 to 30 months even.

@NoobMaster27 plz provide an example of the data you have and the expected result as tables

You can do this in a single if statement. SAS is already looping for us by reading each row one-by-one.
We know that the month number is the number part of Mnth_X separated by _. We can use the scan function to pull this value, which we can then compare. So, the overall logic we want is:
If the Prd_Name is P13 and the month number is between 1 and 4, make doses = 0
Which looks like this:
data want;
    set dose_trn;
  
    if(prd_name = 'P13' AND 1 <= scan(Month, -1, '_') <= 4)
        then doses = 0;
run;

The neat thing about SAS is that it is able to identify that we've pulled out  a number and will do the conversion of a string to a number for us.
If you want to select specific months, you can do this:
data want;
    set dose_trn;
  
    if(prd_name = 'P13' AND scan(Month, -1, '_') IN(1, 3, 4) )
        then doses = 0;
run;

Again, SAS converts the string to a number for us which you can see in the log.

This method using scan fuction in SAS worked for my problem. Thank you.

Sounds like you want the CHANGE command of the old MVS editor WYLBUR where you could do something like change columns 36/37 to '01'+1 in the range of lines that have 'Mnth_' in columns 31/35.  I think systems that used that editor retired a long long time ago.
What I do normally is just replicate the lines and then change them. Easy to do using the arrow keys on the keyboard to move up/down and left/right between the lines.
You could use the SELECT statement to simplify the code.  But you would still need to replicate a lot of lines.
If you really need some way to program it you could use code generation.
You could just write a simple data step to write the lines of code to a file or even just the SAS log.  Then copy/paste them into your program.
data _null_;
   do month=1 to 20;
    put "if Prd_Name = 'P13' and Month= 'Mnth_" month ' then Doses=0;';
   end;
run;

Or you could wrap the code into a macro definition so that you could use the macro language to generate the code:
%do month=1 %to 20;
  if Prd_Name = 'P13' and Month= "Mnth_&month" then Doses=0;
%end;

But you might also want to consider using a look-up table to join with to map PRD_NAME and MONTH values to DOSE values.
data lookup ;
  input prd_name :$20. month :$8 dose;
cards;
P13 Mnth_1 0
P13 Mnth_2 0
;
proc sql; 
  create table Dose_Trn_2 as 
    select a.*,b.dose 
    from Dose_Trn a left join lookup b
      on a.prd_name=b.prd_name and a.month=b.month
  ;
quit;

Or use a INFORMAT, which you define with code or with a dataset so that your code looks more like:
dose = input(cats(prd_name,month),dose.);

